# Input-поле внизу layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Как сделать, чтобы *ScrollView* не перекрывал внизу поле ввода сообщения с кнопкой?

При отображении со скролингом залезает на нижние элементы:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/titlebutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textpassff"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textpass"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:padding="10dp" />

        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/llWriteCommentWall"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btButtonComments"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Comments"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEdittext"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:hint="Write a comment....   "
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btButtonComments"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: скриншот чтоли покажите

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего использовать вертикальный `LinearLayout`:

Сделайте у `ScrollView` высоту 0dp и вес 1, а все что должно быть ниже разместите далее в `LinearLayout` с высотой `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/titlebutton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ffff" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textpass"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:padding="10dp" />

        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llWriteCommentWall"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btButtonComments"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Comments"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEdittext"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:hint="Write a comment....   "
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btButtonComments"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```